# Excel VBA: merge (SUM) rows based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a randomly generated list of languages with different wordcount per file and I need to merge (SUM) function lines based on value in **Column A**.

Basically I need it to merge lines(values) for columns B - J based on the value on Column A. Only if the values are the same otherwise do not merge anything.

More lines for one language means there is more files for that language. If there is more files then I need to get total wordcount by merging the lines.

Please see reference images below:

Source table

[image: Source table]

Updated table

[image: Updated table]

Any ideas?

EDIT1: I have a large macro that loads CSV with all these data and process them. My goal is to have one button macro that will import a CSV and process the data in the formatt I need. There is several dozens of code to make it look like on the screenshot above. Last thing is to merge the cells. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Use a Pivot Table

Comment: Sounds like a pretty straightforward use of `SUMIF`, if you prefer not to use Pivot Tables. What have you tried or researched?

Comment: That wont work because I have a large macro that loads CSV with all these data and process them. My goal is to have one button macro that will import a CSV and process the data in the formatt I need. There is several dozens of code to make it look like on the screenshot above. Last thing is to merge the cells. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: then use `Application.WorksheetFormula.SumIfs()`

Answer (score 3):

Select the leftmost cell BELOW you data and hit the [image: consolidate] button at the "data" tab.
With the new window: mark your range, select "Sum" and at "Use labels in" hit "left column" and "OK"
[image]

This will give you your summed list:
[image]

Just a hint: With record macro ([image]) you get the code for this like:

```
Selection.Consolidate Sources:="[Book1]Sheet2!R2C1:R11C10", Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

And the best part: You can do this with external data! So directly importing from your csv is possible ;)

To do the "real code" is up to you. ;)

Comment: This is actullay helpfull. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. And if there are any questions coming up, just ask :)